# c# Web API custom routing implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I am trying to develop a "strategy" for ASP.NET Core Web API where each "endpoint" (or, in my case, each model) would have multiple controller endpoints, each representing possible action on that model. For Example, `Person` model would have CRUD actions defined on itself, thus it would have defined endpoints in `ReadController`, `InsertController`, `UpdateController` and `DeleteController`. With that being said, I have defined "**ViewService**" which would be used in controller for *View-Model* and *Model-View* operations (ie. validate user input, finalising records to be returnen in HTTP response, ...). On the other hand, each model has its own **DatabaseService**, which is in charge of actions performed in/on database. Those two services are used in all generic actions controllers, where all action controllers inherit from generic abstract controller defined bellow:

```
public abstract class ActionControllerBase<TModel, TDatabaseService, TViewService> : Controller 
    where ...
```

Each model's ViewService inherits from generic IViewService (similar to controllers), and contains attribute where its route prefix is defined:

```
[ControllerEndpoint("/api/Person", typeof(ReadController<Person, IPersonDatabaseService, IPersonViewService>), //other controller action's types defined similar to ReadController)]
public interface IPersonViewService : 
    IReadViewService<Person>, 
    IInsertViewService<Person>, 
    IUpdateViewService<Person>, 
    IDeleteViewService<Person>
{
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having occurs when trying to register base route prefix as valid. I have tried overriding `DefaultControllerActivator` and/or `DefaultControllerFactory` to instantiate correct controller, however problem is that '/api/Person' is not recognised as valid endpoint (I got returned status code 404 and, thus, controller activator or controller factory is not even called). Also, no url starting with "*/api/Person*" is visible in Swagger UI as a valid endpoint.

I am using .NET 7.0

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would say you should have proper Controller used for mapping the paths to each action read/ add/ update.

That way you will use built in features of controller action paths scanning and avoid any custom limbo.

Then you can reference  IPersonViewService inside that controller and call appropriate actions.

```
[ControllerEndpoint("/api/Person", typeof(ReadController<Person, IPersonDatabaseService, IPersonViewService>), //other controller action's types defined similar to ReadController)]
```

should not be part of service class.

Comment: I totally understand where you are going from. Reason for posting my question is because I have lots of models which (in typical case) should be accessed via their respective controllers. Since not all of them have the same sets of functionalities defined on them (some have CRUD, some only read, some read, insert and delete, some read and update, etc.), I was wondering weather my idea of approach would be possible, since it would follow DRY principles for controller endpoints, yet would allow per-model customization if needed.